# Python/Discord: Prevent only certain people from accessing a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am setting up a character creator for a discord RPG and I've made some code which prevents someone from starting the character creator if someone is already doing it:

```
if message.content == "MMO start":
    if not currentcreator == 0:
        await message.channel.send("Someone is already making a profile so please wait")
    currentcreator = message.author
```

However I cant work out how to prevent the second person from going ahead without it cancelling the first person?

Comment: Try using a boolean value to check whether it is being used or not or even maintain a log for all the function calls(delete after a certain time for storage)

Comment: Could i have i bit more detail on doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
character_creating = False

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "MMO start":
        if character_creating:
            await message.channel.send("Someone is already making a profile so please wait")
            return
        character_crearing = True
        

        #then do the character creating code here and at last do
        character_creating = False
```